# Rich Text Mail Merge using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-docs-api

I tried two options for mail merge but I am not able to retain the formatting.
I don't want to save the email content in the HTML file of the code because I want it to be easy to update the email template for someone who does not know coding.

1. Using the regular mail merge code from google apps script where email content is stored in a cell of the sheet. But I want this content to be formatted - bullets, urls, bold etc.
   Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge
2. (Most effective so far) Using advanced version of regular mail merge but the variables cannot be formatted.
   Refernce: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/mail-merge
3. Using a google doc template which has variables that will be filled from spreadsheet using a script. Then this content needs to be emailed without the formatting being lost. I am able to set the variables and send personalized emails, but the formatting (bold, bulleted list, new lines, urls) is being lost. How do I retain the formatting?
   Reference : https://katydecorah.com/code/google-sheets-to-gmail-template/

**Sample Doc Template**

Hello {Name},
Here is your confirmation number {Number}.
**Please bring the following items.**

1. List item
2. List item

Please visit this website www.google.com for more details

Comment: Can you provide your current script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Sure, I am using the code from this link https://katydecorah.com/code/google-sheets-to-gmail-template/

Comment: But my template has more formatting like I mentioned

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `But my template has more formatting like I mentioned`, in order to correctly understand your situation, can you add the script for replicating the issue to your question? And also, can you provide a sample Document? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I've looked at your link, and it's not immediately obvious how to convert it to html. In any event, the entire thing can be done within Google Sheets . ChicagoComputerClasses has an excellent [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2z13YE3kJg) on this exact subject. I know that providing links to external sources is frowned upon, so someone may yet provide the the full code.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer to not save the content in HTML file as I want it to be easy to update for a person who may not be familiar with HTML. So saving the email template in a google doc or spreadsheet cell or drafts is what I prefer.